# How to get match within [ and ] in String using regex

Tags: java, regex

I have a requirement to get the matching string within square brackets [].

For eg., in a String input like `"[***]qwerty"`, 
I should get the match as `"***"` string.

The regex I used in vain is `"\\[(.+)\\]"`

My Java code is as below:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex_custom_delimiter_pattern); //see regex above
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("[***]qwerty");
String delimiter = null;
if (matcher.find()) {
  delimiter = matcher.group(0);
}
```

Any help is appreciated..wondering what I'm missing in the regex that I used :(

Comment: What seems to be problem? Do you get wrong match?

Comment: If I try this, the resulting `delimiter` is `"[***]"`, so the pattern match is working fine.  If the problem is that the brackets shouldn't be there, use `matcher.group(1)` instead of `matcher.group(0)`.  `matcher.group(0)` returns the *entire* matched string, not the string that matches a capture group.

Comment: @ajb thanks. I wanted the result from group(1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should work correctly, but you can use a more efficient expression if the value between `[` and `]` doesn't contain `[` or `]` literally:

```
\\[([^\\]]+)]
```

Or if the value can contain `[` or `]` then:

```
\\[(.+?)\\]
```

Also your main problem is that you are getting group 0 `matcher.group(0)` which is the entire match, your value is stored in group 1 so you need `matcher.group(1)`.

Comment: as an aside comment, the first pattern that can be shorten to `\\[[^]]*]` since `]` is not a special character and in the first position in the character class.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Thank you for your feedback, I didn't want to confuse the OP on why he can put the closing `]` inside the character class without it causing problems.

Comment: @Sniffer In retrospective I realized that you've gone beyond my question to help me understand regex better. Your answer deserves to be correct. Thank you very much indeed!

Answer (score 1):

You need group 1 instead of group 0. Group 0 is the whole match.

```
delimiter = matcher.group(0);
```